# how to align asynchronous reports for a related asset?

Tags: algorithm, interpolation

The example I will give is a train. A train has multiple train-cars and in my system each train car will send me a packet of info on a determined interval. For example, I can guarantee I will have at least 1 packet from each train-car every 10 minutes.

What I want to do is show an animation of the train cars proceeding along the map.

The problem I have is how to align all the data to make a train - visualization with each car in it's relative position to each other - when the data is recorded at different times and without any order relevant to the order of the train cars?

What ends up happening is sometimes car2 will look like it's in front of car1! In the example below, if I showed the data reported for this period, car2 looks like it's on top of car1!

For example

```
CAR | TIME | LOCATION | LOCATION of 1 (guessed, not reported)
1   | 05   |  10,10   | 10,10
2   | 06   |  10,10   | 10,11
3   | 04   |  10,07   | 10,09
```

You may suggest that I look at my own example and visualize the guessed location of the other cars at a specific point. For a train where the route is known this is a good solution (and a likely candidate I'll be implementing). But if you change the scope of the problem from trains on tracks to semi-convoys on roads the guessing solution breaks down. There's no way to know if the first car in the convoy took a turn...

This returns the question to trying to find a reasonable analytical/computational solution to synchronizing the recorded metrics.

Is there a known strategy for dealing with this type of problem? Where do I start my research? Any prefab solutions?

The only solution I can think of that's analytical will be to find the smallest window of available data from the data points to create the smallest possible frame of data, select the mean time for the frame and then approximate the location for the other points based on the point closest to the mean.

This is very close to the strategy I disregarded earlier where I use the know distance between the cars to guess where carA is based on carC. Because it's a train I can assume that the speed is the same for all cars at any time. In a semi convoy this isn't true, semiACar1 could be slightly slower or faster than semiBcar1.

So by now I think you understand the problem and where I am .

Thanks for your ideas and interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have reported data, interpolate /extrapolate the positions. If your temporal resolution is high enough this should work just fine.

If your temporal resolution isn't good enough, first model the likely track, then interpolate along the track.